# Redirecting to different controller in webapi in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm new to WebApi in Asp.Net and my scenario is like this. I've a webapi application with 2 controllers say Controller1 and Controller2 and controller1 has a method called Index and controller2 has GetProducts method. So when a client calls url : api/controller1/Index then they should be redirected to a getProducts method in Controller2 .I know that they can call controller2 directly but  My requirement is in such a way that they should call controller1 initially and when they are redirected to controller2 ,the url should be like api/controller2/GetProducts . Please tell me how to get this.

Comment: thanks frosdqy , it worked like a champ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ApiController.Redirect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx) method.

```
return Redirect(
    Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Controller2", action = "GetProducts" })
);
```